# Setting variables in Nestjs services do not store the variable's updated state

Tags: typescript, nestjs

So I have been working with nest.js Which I am building a discord bot inside of.
My bot.service.ts calls a function from app.service.ts that sets a variable `isBotHealthy` which gets displayed through the Api.

my problem is that i can't seem to get `isBotHealthy` to display anything other that it's default value of false

bot.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class BotService {
  private readonly intents: IntentsBitField
  public readonly client: HelixClient
  private config: HelixConfiguration
  private logger: Logger

  constructor(
    private appService: AppService,
  ) {
    ...
  }

  /**
   * Starts the bot.
   */
  public async start() {
    const client = this.client
    this.logger.log('Starting HelixBot...')
    try {
      this.logger.debug('Logging in...')
      await client.login(this.config.discord.bot.token)
      this.logger.debug('Logged in.')
      this.logger.debug('Setting bot health to true...')
      const healthStatus = this.appService.setBotHealth(true) // <=== This is the spot I change the status
      this.logger.debug(`Bot health set to ${healthStatus}.`)
    }
    catch (err) {
      this.logger.error('Error occurred: ' + err)
      this.appService.setBotHealth(false)
    }

    client.once(Events.ClientReady, () => {
      this.logger.log(`${this.client.user.displayName} is ready!`)
    })
  }
}
```

app.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  public botIsHealthy: boolean = false
  private logger: Logger

  constructor() {
    this.logger = new Logger('AppService')
  }

  ...

  public setBotHealth(health: boolean) {
    this.logger.debug(`Setting botIsHealthy to ${health}...`)
    this.botIsHealthy = health
    this.logger.debug(`botIsHealthy set to ${this.botIsHealthy}.`)
    return this.botIsHealthy
  }

  getBotHealth() {
    this.logger.debug(`Getting botIsHealthy...`)
    this.logger.debug(`botIsHealthy: ${this.botIsHealthy}`)
    return this.botIsHealthy
  }

  public async getData() {
    this.logger.debug('Getting data from /api ...')
    return {
      name: 'Helix Discord API',
      description: 'This is a Discord API',
      version: '1.0.0',
      apiStatus: 'healthy',
      botStatus: this.getBotHealth() ? 'healthy' : 'unhealthy', // <== This is where it gets returned
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunetly I can't seem to find what the error is, the functions get called properly and the "set the value to true, but it does not stay at true. Setting it in the constructor yeilds the same problem. Is there something i am doing wrong?